# maven dependecies can't be imported

Tags: java, maven, import, dependencies, pom.xml

I have set-up a mave project in Eclipse, I added the project dependencies to the pom.xml which was created by eclipse automatically.

```
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId> org.springframework.core </artifactId>
           <version>3.0.6.RELEASE </version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now when I import the Jdbc template in one of the classes, I get the import can't be resolved error

```
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
```

Are dependencies added during compilation time, or execution time only? if they are only available at execution time, then how can I compile the code?

Comment: How did you import the project?  If you imported it as a Maven project, then Eclipse knows to regenerate the project when it detects POM changes.  If you generated an Eclipse project by using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, then you'll have to re-run the command in order to let Eclipse know about the new libs.

Comment: I didn't import the project, I created a new project. Also, maybe its worth noting that I skipped the archetype selection. But I don't see how this might affect the dependencies.

Comment: Agreed -- I do not think that it has to do with skipping that step.

Answer (score 2):

One way to verify if maven dependencies are added to your project or not in eclipse is under the project ->libraries->Maven Dependencies, all the dependency you have added in your pom.xml should be present

In your case spring-jdbc{version}.jar should there else try to update the project, while updating the project by default all the dependencies would be downloaded to your home directory/.m2/repository. If you find your dependencies are not present check your proxy settings. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple problem you have is that the class `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` is contained in the following artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but not in the spring-core nor as transitive dep. Apart from that you should first check to build the project on command line with Maven and afterward import it into Eclipse.